# Unable to maintain JSF ViewState within a dataTable component

Tags: jsf, datatable, viewstate

I'm working an inherited JSF app. Still quite new to it.

Here's a screenshot of the page I'm working with: http://goo.gl/GidpCD.  This is some exam software and what you're looking at is question administration.  On this screen the user can write the question, cite the question source, write answers, associate to a category and associate images.

Where I'm getting stuck is when I add/delete answers down toward the bottom.

I'm suspicious that my issue is with ViewState.

When I click the add or delete answers.  The page reloads and I lose my file associations within a JSF dataTable component.  ViewState is maintained in all of the other form elements on the page, it's just those files within that dataTable that I can't seem to get my head wrapped around.  Here's that JSF dataTable component (I'll list the code in it's entirety below):

```
<h:dataTable id="table0" value="#{adminQuestions.filesList}" var="file" columnClasses="id,title,selected last" rendered="true" >
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">File</f:facet>
        <h:graphicImage value="#{file.path2}" alt="" />
    </h:column>

    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Title</f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{file.title}" />
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Select files</f:facet>
        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{file.selected}" />
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

Here's the JSF button compnent to fire the add add answer method:

```
<h:commandButton value="#{msgs.addButton}" action="#{adminQuestions.addQuestionToAnswerRow}" />
```

And here's that `add answer` method:

```
public String addQuestionToAnswerRow() {
    if(this.questionToAnswerList.size() < 8) {
        // set the scroll
        if(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getMessageList().size() > 0) {
            this.scroll = false;
        }
        else {
            this.scroll = true;
        }
        //Create a new answer, set the current question, and add it to the collection
        Answers answer_local = new Answers();
        QuestionToAnswer qta_local = new QuestionToAnswer();
        answer_local.setTitle(this.inputTextAnswer);
        answer_local.setDescription(this.inputTextAnswer);
        answer_local.setCorrect(this.correctAnswer);
        qta_local.setAnswers(answer_local);
        qta_local.setAnswer(this.questionToAnswerList.size() + 1);
        qta_local.setQuestions(this.question);
        this.questionToAnswerList.add(qta_local);
        // reset the input fields
        this.inputTextAnswer = "";
        this.correctAnswer = false;

        List<File1> thisFilesList = getFilesList();

        QuestionsToFiles qtf;
        List<QuestionsToFiles> qtfc = new ArrayList<QuestionsToFiles>();
        if(this.filesList != null) {
            for(Iterator<File1> entries = this.filesList.iterator(); entries.hasNext();) {
                File1 file_temp = entries.next();
                if(file_temp.isSelected()) {
                    qtf = new QuestionsToFiles();
                    qtf.setQuestions(this.question);
                    qtf.setFile1(file_temp);
                    qtfc.add(qtf);
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
    else {
        JSFUtils.addErrorMessage("No more than eight answers are allowed: ", "The question cannot have more than eight answers");
        return null;
    }
}
```

Here's the JSF button component to fire the delete method

```
<h:commandButton value="#{msgs.deleteButton}" action="#{adminQuestions.deleteQuestionToAnswerRow(a)}" />
```

And the delete method:

```
public String deleteQuestionToAnswerRow(QuestionToAnswer qta_local) {
    // set the scroll
    if(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getMessageList().size() > 0) {
        this.scroll = false;
    }
    else {
        this.scroll = true;
    }
    //Iterate through the category exam collection and delete the associated category so it's reflected on the page
    for (Iterator<QuestionToAnswer> itr = this.questionToAnswerList.iterator(); itr.hasNext();) {
        QuestionToAnswer qta_temp = itr.next();
        if(qta_temp == qta_local) {
            qta_temp.setQuestions(null);
            qta_temp.setAnswers(null);
            itr.remove();
            return null;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

- [Here's a Gist the XHTML page in it's entirety](http://goo.gl/gakOpP)
- [Here's a Gist the Java class in it's entirety](http://goo.gl/DtEwmR)

Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: not sure about this, but why don't you ajaxify the add button without rendering the datatable again?

Comment: Please stop overgeneralizing all tags as JSTL. Carefully read our JSTL wiki page to learn what JSTL really is: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info

Comment: Yea, I'm still definitely on the front side of the JSF learning curve.  Thanks for clearing that part up @BalusC :)